# javascript adding minutes in a loop

Tags: javascript

Can't figure this out, from 9:00 to 10:00 everything's correct, but then it all goes haywire. after 10:00 it jumps to 11:15 and then to 12:30

I am simply adding minutes to a date/time to increment an array in 15 minute intervals, is it that I can only add a maximum of 60 minutes ??

```
function pad(val,max) { 
        var str = val.toString(); 
        return str.length < max ? pad("0" + str, max) : str;
}

function cboHrs(){
    var now = new Date(); 
    now.setHours(9);
    var hrs = [];
    for (var i=1;i<36;i++){
        var hr = {}; 
        now.setMinutes(i*15);
        hr.txt = pad(now.getHours(),2) +':'+pad(now.getMinutes(),2);
        hr.val = hr.txt; 
        hrs.push(hr);
        }
    return hrs;
}
console.log(cboHrs());
```

Comment: Can you post the `pad` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anthony got to the actual problem before me...

> After the 5th iteration, you are setting the minutes to become 75 (ie,
>   5 * 15 = 75) which is an 1 hour and 15 minutes which is why the next
>   value after 10:00 becomes 11:15
>   - Anthony Forloney

This code should work to set the time correctly.

```
function cboHrs(){
    var now = new Date(); 
    var hrs = [];
    for (var i=1;i<36;i++){
        var hr = {};
        // add another hour every 4th iteration
        now.setHours(9 + parseInt(i / 4));
        // add 15 minutes every iteration, starting back at 0 on the 4th
        now.setMinutes((i % 4) * 15);
        hr.txt = pad(now.getHours(),2) +':'+pad(now.getMinutes(),2);
        hr.val = hr.txt; 
        hrs.push(hr);
        }
    return hrs;
}
```

Comment: No problem. I actually would have expected the same behavior you were expecting and as a result would have run into the same problem, so I'm glad this question got me thinking about it, potentially saving me, and hopefully others, some time.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies within the `now.setMinutes(i*15);` line of code. After the 5th iteration, you are setting the minutes to become `75` (ie, `5 * 15 = 75`) which is an `1 hour and 15 minutes` which is why the next value after `10:00` becomes `11:15`